What can be the name of tokens which traps investors in a high APY staking program? (by offering them a high APY)
I called it myself a STAKING TRAP, because i didn't find any term for this type of scam. now maybe you ask yourself what i mean exactly by a STAKING TRAP? it is RUG PULL method by offering victims a high APY and traping their investments in a staking program while the first liquidity will be withdrawn by dev team and the price falls thousands units. In fact the marKet cap is not provided by real people.
Check EVMOS as a reference.
IS THERE ANY TERM FOR THIS TYPE OF SCAM? OR MAY I COIN MINE AS "STAKING TRAP"?
